# Android Digital Clock time change using TimePicker

Tags: android, view

How to change the time in Digital clock view by picking the time from TimePicker Dialog??

Answer (score 0):

The `DigitalClock` widget only shows the system time. You cannot use it to display other times. Hence, there is no way to have it display a time chosen by a user through a `TimePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has somehow related to Set alarm activity in previous android releases.
I see that set Alarm in android 2.3.3 is what you ask? there is a digital clock above the entered alarm time by user, so when user set the alarm time, the digital clock changed identically to alarm, the digital time has not related to system time as showed.

I think this done by coding, not by digital clock.

[image: Alarm Digital time]